# Is there a standard notation for the set of closed points of a scheme?

Tags: reference-request, notation

I was wondering whether there is a standard notation for the set of closed points of a scheme $X$? Liu uses in his book the notation $X^0$ (Remark 3.50), but the stacks-project uses $X^0$ for the set of generic points of the irreducible components of $X$ ([Tag 0EMF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0EMF)).

I am grateful for any kind of remark or reference about this!

Comment: I believe that $X^0$ or $X_0$ is relatively common, but there isn't a consensus to my knowledge. Be sure to recall the meaning when using the notation in a paper.